# Why does this mass equation not work in this calculus application problem?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, first-order-logic, applications

This *is* a homework problem which I have already solved, but I want to know why my first approach did not work. **I have already asked my professor this question, but he did not explain it very well.**

#### Problem

[image: Problem]

The answer for the time is 5.78 min.

Initially I approached this by deriving the following equation while considering the movement of the salt into and out of the tank:

$m(t) = m_i+(\dot{m_{in}}-\dot{m_{out}})t$

$m(t)$ = current salt in tank

$m_i$ = initial salt in tank

$\dot{m_{in}}$ = rate of salt flowing in

$\dot{m_{out}}$ = rate of salt flowing out

#### Workings

Now since the rate of salt flowing out depends on the concentration of salt in the tank I add:

$\dot{m_{out}} = \frac{m(t)}{v}\cdot\frac{dv_{out}}{dt}$

$m(t)$ = current salt in the tank

$v$ = volume of tank

$\frac{dv_{out}}{dt}$ = rate of water flow out of tank

After subbing terms I get:

$m(t) = m_i+((0.05)*6-\frac{m(t)}{50}*6)t$

Since the concentration of salt in the tank is just $\frac{m(t)}{50} = C$

$c(t) = \frac{0.5+0.3*t}{(1+\frac{6}{50}*t)50} = 0.03$

I simply divide the right side by 50 and solve for $t$ to find when the concentration gets to be $0.03kg/L$. But I end up with the wrong answer.

#### Question

what is the flaw in logic in my equation? To me it makes perfect sense and in other cases it will work. I always thought that if I wrote a math equation that made sense and that I thought to be true, everything should work out.

Comment: The equation just after "After subbing terms I get" is not right. The rate of exit of salt is variable, and was fairly low at the beginning, and higher later.

Comment: I thought writing $\frac{m(t)}{v}$ accounted for that? My logic is that $m(t)$ is the current salt in the tank, divided by the volume (50L which remains constant) gives concentration and then multiplied by the rate of outflow (6L/min), would give the rate of mass leaving.

Comment: The amount of salt in the tank earlier was lower, so the outflow rate was lower.

Comment: That's just it, I thought using $m(t)$ would account for that; I thought when the concentration of salt was low $m(t)$ would represent that fact, as well as when it was high. That's why I'm confused. What would I have to replace the term ( $\frac{m(t)}{50}*6$ ) with to account for this?

Comment: Your post seems to indicate that you solved the problem, presumably by setting up and solving a DE for $m(t)$. That is the only way I can think of. Maybe after solving one could use the solution to see what $\frac{6}{50}m(t)$ could be replaced by.

Comment: Your first equation ought to read $m'(t)=m'_{in}-m'_{out}$, which gives rise to the differential equation $dm=(.3-\frac 6{50} m)dt$.

Comment: @lulu that *is* how the correct answer is derived. Then it is equated to $\frac{d[cv]}{dt}$. I posted this question because I want to gain an intuition for these problems and why my intuition was not correct.

Comment: @Klik the problem is with your first equation.  What you wrote just gives the first order approximation, as in $f'(t)\sim \frac {f(t)-f(0)}{t}\implies tf'(t)\sim f(t)-f(0)$

Comment: @lulu Ok, so my equation assumes a constant relationship, linear relationship... If I relate this example to displacement $s(t) = s'(t)*t + 0.5*s''(t)*t^2$ Am I leaving out the acceleration term? I get the feeling that I could replace my term with something that has a $t^2$ term.

Comment: @Klik.  No.  Just intuitively, the answer has to be exponential in nature.  That is, $m'(t)$ will start off low but then asymptotically reach $m'_{in}(t)$.  You'll need infinitely many correction terms, of all orders.  That's why the ODE is so good...it takes care of all of those terms simultaneously.  Of course, it's no use if you can't solve the ODE but that's not an issue here (first order linear, constant coefficients even).

Comment: Ok. I will think about what you've said and do some experimenting with numbers. Thanks for the time.